# Is this definition about an operation on a group wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

> Let $(G,+)$ is a group and $G'\neq\varnothing$ $\varphi\colon G\to G'$ is bijective,define an operation $*$ on $G'$ by $g'*h' \colon=\varphi^{-1}(g')+\varphi^{-1}(h')$ $g',h'\in G'$ then $(G,*)$ is a group

The operation on $G'$ should be closed on $G'$,but the definition imply that the $g'*h'$ belongs to $G$, which contradict the defition of group.

Comment: well, it says $(G,*)$ is a group, so it's wrong but not for the reason you gave. $g*h$ should be defined for $g,h \in G$, not $g,h \in G'$ (or what they call $g',h' \in G'$). Also, I don't know why they explicitly say "$G' \not = \emptyset$", since that is implied by $\varphi : G \to G'$ being a bijection ($G \not = \emptyset$ since groups have an identity element).

Comment: Please don't use images; they are not searchable, they don't display properly in every display type, and they often clash with accessibility software.

Comment: @mathworker21: It's a typo (I transcribed the image as-is). It's meant to be "$(G',*)$".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is wrong. I suspect that who wrote that meant$$g'*h'=\varphi\bigl(\varphi^{-1}(g')+\varphi^{-1}(h')\bigr).$$

Comment: Yes, I have seen this called "Structure transport". You lift a structure to an other set via a bijection.

Comment: @user661541 Yes, that's the usual expression for this way of defining an operation.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos did you read my comment above??

Comment: Yes. And I disagree with it. You claim that “it says $(G,*)$ is group”. Not really. What it says is that $(G,+)$ is a group and the goal define a group operation $*$ on $G'$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it says that at the end of the question

Comment: @mathworker21 Right. As you have already been told, it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be $g'*h'=\phi(\phi^{-1}(g')+\phi^{-1}(h'))$

and $(G', *)$ is a group